# clojure string null check failed with string/blank

Tags: clojure

```
(defn get-coll-id [^String coll_id]
  (log/info "coll_id: " coll_id)
  (if (string/blank? coll_id)
    (let [collVal (get-coll-val)]
      (log/info "collVal: " collSeqVal)
      (format "C%011.0f" collVal))
    coll_id))
```

The log shows "coll_id: null". However, string/blank did not detect the null, and thus log of collVal is skipped. What is the method to check null string?

Comment: `"null"` is a value which prints as `null` and is not blank. Have you checked what value you actually have?

Comment: You could log `(pr-str coll_id)` to get a less ambiguous report. `pr-str` stringifies a value in such a way that it could be re-read by the Clojure reader, so, in effect (to make a long story short), strings are quoted and nil is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something (perhaps a DB?) is giving you the string `"null"` for `coll_id`, or perhaps `(log/info ...)` converts a Clojure `nil` into the string `"null"`.

Consider this code:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.string :as str]
  ))

(defn get-coll-id [^String coll_id]
  (println "coll_id: " coll_id)
  (if (str/blank? coll_id)
    (println :blank)
    coll_id))

(dotest
  (newline)
  (println :v1)
  (spyx (get-coll-id nil))

  (newline)
  (println :v2)
  (spyx (get-coll-id (pr-str nil)))
)
```

with output:

```
:v1
coll_id:  nil
:blank
(get-coll-id nil) => nil

:v2
coll_id:  nil
(get-coll-id (pr-str nil)) => "nil"
```

No matter what you do, you get either the value `nil` or the string `"nil"` printed.

Since I haven't used Java for a while, I tried to force it to generate the string `"null"`, but calling `o.toString()` for a `null` value creates a
`NullPointerException`, so that is not the answer.

---

**Update**

As amalloy points out, `String.valueOf()` will convert a Java `null` into the string `"null"`:

```java
package demo;
public class Demo {
  public static String go() {
    Object o = null;
    return String.valueOf( o );
  }
}
```

when run:

```clj
  (newline)
  (spyx :v3 (demo.Demo/go))
```

with result

```
:v3 (demo.Demo/go) => "null"
```

---

As to your original question, the `nil?` function could be used:

```
(defn blank-or-nil?
  [s]
  (or (nil? s)
    (str/blank? s)))

(defn get-coll-id [^String coll_id]
  (println "coll_id: " coll_id)
  (if (blank-or-nil? coll_id)
    (println "found blank-or-nil coll_id")
    coll_id))
```

which then prints `found blank-or-nil coll_id` when passed a nil value.  However, this could confuse things if your are passed the string `"null"` or the string `"nil"`.

You need to clarify which value is the input, then track down the source.

---

The above code is based on my favorite [template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Comment: `(let [^String s nil] (String/valueOf s))` is what you were looking for. That's a good approximation for a Java program expecting a string but getting null. We need the typehint because it's overloaded, and Clojure guesses the wrong overload if we just pass a bare nil.